Can a person challenge a criminal charge if it never went to court?
Is it possible for a person challenge or expunge a 25 year old felony charge that comes up on a background check if no court records exist because the case was never brought to court?
What is the process to clear that person's name?

@doneal24 and the person who upvoted the comment:  OK, but then please vote to reopen the dupe!!!

What do you mean by "challenge"? Do they dispute that they were charged with the crime ("it was a different John Smith, not me.")?

@MichaelHall Why should the other one be reopened? If that one isn't a good question, why is this one any better?

@Barmar, because it wasn't closed for not being a good question, it was closed because it seemed to be asking for legal advice.  And questions aren't closed because they aren't "good".  Good is subjective, and that is what the voting buttons are for.  In any case, it underwent a major edit after it was closed.  Does that answer your question?

And although the original question wasn't mine, this edit is, so by "challenge" I mean some sort of due process to clear a person's name.

As pointed out in the comments there, it generally isn't possible to expunge arrests records.

@Barmar, questions shouldn't be answered in comments, and it's asking about a charge, not an arrest.

An answer that just says "no" would be considered a poor answer. There are probably special exceptions that a real lawyer would be able to explain, I'm not qualified.
